# Is there such a thing as the derivative of an integer?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, integers

A polynomial has a square divisor (i.e., a double root) if and only if that root divides the derivative of that polynomial. Is there a corresponding algebraic definition of the derivative of an integer, so that an integer $n$ has a square divisor $p^2$ if an only if $p$ divides the derivative of $n$? Another way of putting it: $gcd(n,n')$ gives you the square factors of $n$. If such a derivative existed, it would be a useful tool in factoring integers.

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: Yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative

Comment: It wouldn't be a useful tool, because you can't calculate the derivative without factoring the number.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Since you mentioned it first, would you mind elaborating on that to form an answer so this no longer sits unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for the sake of removing this question from the unanswered queue.

The answer is $\color{blue}{\text{yes}}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative

The OP was hoping this might give a method to factorise numbers, but as Professor Vector points out ... the calculation of the derivative requires factorising the number. $\ddot \frown$

But on a happier note ... the Circumcenter, Orthocenter, Symmedian point and $X(879)$ form an Orthic System.

[image]